# Cron does not work in ubuntu (digitalocean)

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron, digital-ocean

I am trying to run echo php command with cron in every minute. this is crontab line:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/a.php
```

and a.php is:

```
<?php
 echo "Test\n";
?>
```

But i think cron is not working because i did not see any output since 5 minutes.

Result of  service status cron is "cron start/running, process 919"

Comment: Where does it say "5" minutes in your crontab action?

Comment: i just say, i am waiting for  5 minutes.  * * * * *  stars does not mean every one minute?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I misunderstood. I assume you are checking the Cron-Log. Are you sure you are looking at the correct file? Refers to [this Q/A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log) for info on logging location.

Comment: thank you @BrandonWhite i was waiting for the output in terminal now i see the results in syslog. thank you it is working

Comment: Are you sure that the user running the cronjob has permission to access the file?

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking in your sys log for the information. Are you sure you are looking at the correct file? Refers to [this Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log) for info on logging location.

Comment: The output of the script might turn up in your mail spool (`/var/mail/[user]`). Check this too, if you do not receive local mail.

Comment: why would it be in the mail spool? I can't imagine that ever happening based on the information provided.

Comment: @Dagon It is common for cron to take all stdout from a cronjob and send it to the user as an email. So, in this case, the user would get an email every minute from cron that says "Test"

Comment: only if it is set up to do so, it wont magically do it by itself

Comment: @Dagon From the cron man: "_When executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of the crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO  environment variable  in  the crontab, if such exists)_" Mail will end up in the mail spool, unless it is redirected or read locally!

Comment: OP never said he used MAILTO.

Comment: @Dagon Having cron set up to email the owner of the crontab is the *normal* setup for Ubuntu (and Redhat and Debian and Centos and Fedora...) You can unset it, but if you didn't do anything, it is likely set to email you.

Comment: its not the default on any of my installs - i must be special

Comment: @Dagon Please check your mail spool in /var/mail to ensure you aren't stubbornly sending out false information.

Comment: no cron reports but a lot of "This is a RAID status update from mpt-statusd.  The mpt-status
program reports that one of the RAIDs changed state:
"